# Printed my SNCF ticket and lost it?

Tags: trains, tickets, france, sncf

I'm travelling from Lannion to Paris. I booked the train ticket on line, but was told I'd have to print it at the station. I did that before I left Paris. Now I've lost the printed tickets. Ugh.

Can I cancel the tickets and get a refund then rebook? Or modify the booking slightly and reprint? Or do I just have to buy new tickets?

Comment: Yeah, it was a classic ticket as e-ticket wasn't an option when I bought that one online. I ended up buying another. If I had cancelled the ticket I also wouldn't have been able to get a refund without turning in the hard copy tickets at an SNCF booth. Expensive mistake...

Answer (score 10):

If it is a "e-billet" (e-ticket), what you've printed in the station is just a reminder and you can reprint it the same way with your "reference client" (the 6-letter code) and the payment card you used (to identify you).

If it is a "classic" ticket ("IATA" in SNCF language), you have to buy a new one.

You can look in the confirmation mail you received from the SNCF if you see the sentence "Vous avez choisi : le service e-billet". In that case, it's a e-ticket that you can reprint.

Source: http://aide.voyages-sncf.com/billet-sncf-perdu

Comment: not sure you can print e-billet at the station, though

Comment: @njzk2, you're right, it seems it's not possible anymore to print the "memo" (reminder). http://aide.voyages-sncf.com/le-e-billet

Comment: if it is a ebillet, the controller could even check online with your name if you ask him